# Find date for not dated commit?

Tags: git, parsing, github, commit

I'm doing a git log to list all commits and then parse them.
With this command:

```
git log --encoding=UTF-8 --date=local --pretty=format:'%H,%P,%at,%ct,%an,%s'
```

In some weird repos i get commits without the date in both author and commit dates.
I tried with the simple:

```
git log
```

and what i got was a 1970 date.

A repo where this happens is [SamWM/jQuery-Plugins](https://github.com/SamWM/jQuery-Plugins), for example in the commit `e9dddaf24c9de45d9b4efdf38eff7c30eb200f48`.

Although in GitHub we have and interesting date when we go look for it.

Can anybody help me get an interesting date for this commit that should be somewhere in the middle of the other ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git show --format=raw` shows:

```
commit e9dddaf24c9de45d9b4efdf38eff7c30eb200f48
tree d63aeb159635cb231e191505a95a129a3b4a7b38
parent 9276202f1c0dcc360433df222c90f7874558f072
author SamWM <sam@webmonkeysolutions.com> 1288370243 --700
committer SamWM <sam@webmonkeysolutions.com> 1288370243 --700
```

The timezone information here is invalid, and I'm not sure how he author managed to create this. Other commits do use the correct `-0700` format.

You can convert this using GNU date, with the knowledge that `--700` is supposed to be `-0700`:

```
$ TZ=Etc/GMT+7 date -d @1288370243
Fri 29 Oct 09:37:23 GMT+7 2010
```

so the correct answer in Git's usual format is `Fri 29 Oct 09:37:23 2010 -0700`.

Note: I'm using `TZ=Etc/GMT+7`, not `GMT-7`. You can see by running the same command with different commits that do have correct time zone information that the result is exactly what it's supposed to be. `date`'s time zone conversion is exactly the wrong way around for what's needed here, and by negating the offset I'm cancelling out the error.

You can, in a local copy, fix such commits using `git hash-object` and `git replace`. First, a sanity check that my commands are in order:

```
$ git cat-file commit e9dddaf24c9de45d9b4efdf38eff7c30eb200f48 |
> git hash-object -t commit -w --stdin
e9dddaf24c9de45d9b4efdf38eff7c30eb200f48
```

This command loaded the specified commit, wrote it back unmodified, and showed the rewritten commit's hash. I'm using this as a sanity check: if I got a different hash, something would have to be wrong in my command.

Now, it's possible to insert something to create a fixed commit:

```
$ git cat-file commit e9dddaf24c9de45d9b4efdf38eff7c30eb200f48 |
> sed -e 's/--700/-0700/' |
> git hash-object -t commit -w --stdin
46694249ed3d519b0c934222520b9dc6d8557fa1
```

and use that fixed commit instead:

```
$ git replace e9dddaf24c9de45d9b4efdf38eff7c30eb200f48 46694249ed3d519b0c934222520b9dc6d8557fa1
```

After that, all references to `e9dddaf24c9de45d9b4efdf38eff7c30eb200f48` will look at `46694249ed3d519b0c934222520b9dc6d8557fa1` instead, and `git show e9dddaf24c9de45d9b4efdf38eff7c30eb200f48` now starts with:

```
commit e9dddaf24c9de45d9b4efdf38eff7c30eb200f48
Author: SamWM <sam@webmonkeysolutions.com>
Date:   Fri Oct 29 09:37:23 2010 -0700

    Update version number, make text formatting and indentation consistent with the rest of the code
```

Comment: @rtfpessoa You do need to use raw to check the problem, but you can locally fix the problem so that you will never suffer from it again, and I've amended my answer to show how.

Comment: @rtfpessoa You don't need to push to the repository, you can create the new objects in your local clone of that repository like I did, and you still see the original commit IDs.

Comment: @rtfpessoa That's true, it is indeed a very specific fix, but it's also a very specific situation. I've never seen anything like it before or read about it, ever; I'm pretty sure this is not a widespread bug and very few repositories will be affected by this. You have seen it in multiple repositories, do they perhaps contain commits from the same author?

Comment: @rtfpessoa I think GitHub uses custom logic for that, meaning it effectively uses `git show --format=raw` and converts the timestamp to a string manually. That allows it additional control over the output format.

Comment: so this means that git log with `--date=raw` and `%ad` has a bug because it is not showing the raw date value. Right?

Comment: @rtfpessoa Possibly, but I can't say for sure. `--date=raw` still needs to extract the date from the line `author SamWM <sam@webmonkeysolutions.com> 1288370243 --700`, and it wouldn't surprise me if Git is unable to determine that `1288370243 --700` is supposed to be a date. `git show --format=raw` doesn't have that problem, because it shows the raw headers unmodified, so it doesn't have to figure out which parts of those headers are dates.